# ggplot2::geom_bar() positive and negative bars around zero

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set containing the scaled expression value of thousands of genes from samples isolated using two different tubes. I wanted to do some calculation on this data set https://www.sendspace.com/file/4ebpk3 using these two functions and plot the result:

```html
#Create a function to calculate molecular distance
mol.distance <- function(df, grp){
  x = df[grp]
  x = as.numeric(x)
  y = as.numeric(df)
  mean.x = mean(x)
  difference = y - mean.x
}

#Create a function to calculate median difference
med.diff <- function(df){
  x = as.numeric(df)
  result = median(x)
}
```

The idea is, first I calculate the distance using the first formula. Then, using the second formula, the median value of distances from each samples were calculated. This median values were then plotted in geom_bar.

```
    `#Calculating molecular distance
distance <- apply(clean.merged, 1, mol.distance, grp = (1:40))
rownames(distance) <- colnames(clean.merged)

med.distance <- apply(distance, 1, med.diff)
med.distance <- round(med.distance, digits = 4)

distance1 <- cbind(med.distance, samp.name, iso.tube)
colnames(distance1) <- c('Molecular_Distance', 'Sample_Name', 'Isolation_Tube')

#Plot the result
dist.plot <- ggplot(as.data.frame(distance1), aes(Sample_Name, Molecular_Distance))
dist.plot + geom_bar(stat = 'identity', aes(fill = Isolation_Tube)) +
  ggtitle('Molecular Distance') + coord_flip()`
```

As expected, the result are floating around zero, with mixed positive and negative values. However, when I plotted the result in bar plot, it looks like this: [How my bar plot looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWkNM.jpg)

Meanwhile, I expected something more like this: [How I expected it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPrXG.png)

I'm quite new to programming, so I don't know where I messed up. Please let me know what you thought. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput(head(clean.merged, 20))` in the question, please? Also, in the second `apply` shouldn't it be `apply(clean.merged, 1, etc)`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas Hi, the clean.merged data set contains 80 columns. I'm not sure that I can post the output here. Can you suggest where should I put it so that people can get access to it without flooding the text body? Sorry, I'm very new to programming stuffs. Regarding the second apply, I put `apply(distance, 1, med.diff)` because I need to find the median of each samples in distance. I will edit the question for clarity. Thank you.

Comment: @TaufikMP Please add the data to this free space `https://www.sendspace.com/` you could upload in csv type and then add the link to download to your post.

Comment: @Duck Got it. I've done adding the link to the data set. Thank you.

Comment: @TaufikMP I have sketched a solution without `samp.name` and `iso.tube`. It is similar to what you want. You could format latter with the rest of your vars.

Comment: @Duck Your answer solved the problem. Much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @TaufikMP Great ! If you feel that the answer was helpful for you, you could accept the answer by clicking the tick on the left side of the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the data provided and avoiding `samp.name` and `iso.tube` which are not present in the post, here a possible solution:

```
#Data
clean.merged <- read.csv('clean.merged.csv')
#Functions
#Create a function to calculate molecular distance
mol.distance <- function(df, grp){
  x = df[grp]
  x = as.numeric(x)
  y = as.numeric(df)
  mean.x = mean(x)
  difference = y - mean.x
}

#Create a function to calculate median difference
med.diff <- function(df){
  x = as.numeric(df)
  result = median(x)
}

distance <- apply(clean.merged, 1, mol.distance, grp = (1:40))
rownames(distance) <- colnames(clean.merged)

med.distance <- apply(distance, 1, med.diff)
med.distance <- round(med.distance, digits = 4)

distance1 <- data.frame(med.distance)
colnames(distance1) <- c('Molecular_Distance')
distance1$Sample_Name <- rownames(distance1)

ggplot(distance1, aes(Sample_Name, Molecular_Distance))+ 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', fill='orange',color='black') +
  ggtitle('Molecular Distance') + coord_flip()
```

[image]

I believe the issue was due to not keeping data in a dataframe. I added that to the code. For the variables not present you could add to the same dataframe `distance1`.